No access to external python documentation of numpy library in pycharm
Pycharm is unable to access the documentation of numpy, and all other installed libraries. The runs correctly, but no inline documentation with a description of the function is provided when highlighting and pressing ctrl + q. I use a miniconda environment in which I used the console to conda install the libraries used.
import numpy as np

x = [0.0,0.5,0.7]
y = np.sin(x) # press ctrl+q while highlighting this function

print(y) 

Screenshot of the inline documentation for numpy, the link to the documentation 404s
The link goes to a 404 webpage: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.sin.htm.
To me that seems a likely cause of the lack of a description.
Same problems persist with other libraries, like matplotlib.
screenshot of inline documentation for matplotlib.pyplot
Here the link leads does reach a webpage with (deprecated) documentation, but the common English description of the function does not appear in the documentation shown in pycharm https://matplotlib.org/2.0.2/api/pyplot_api.html .
Am I missing something obvious? Inline documentation seems to be a pretty basic function of an IDE, even if I were to somehow replace the link for the numpy library, surely there is a better way to get documentation without having to setup every library by hand?
I've tried switching interpreters, but got the same problems. I have invalidated the cache and restarted pycharm. I have also tried changing the docstring format to Numpy. I've gone through a post asking a similar question 4 years ago. However, the solution of changing the adress pycharm tries to retrieve the documenation from has also not worked (maybe the link to that library was no longer valid?)
EDIT: by changing the address for numpy to https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/{element.qname}.html (a typo in the answer I got the link from) link pycharm provides now goes to the correct source of documentation. However, the description is still not being shown in the IDE.

This could be due to a few reasons:
a. PyCharm settings:
Ensure that Quick Documentation is enabled: Go to Settings/Preferences > Tools > Python Integrated Tools > Docstrings > Docstring format and make sure it's set to "NumPy" or "reStructuredText".
Check if "Show quick documentation on mouse move" is enabled: Go to Settings/Preferences > Editor > General > Other and look for this option.
b. Conda environment configuration:
Make sure PyCharm is correctly configured to use your Conda environment.
Verify that the libraries are installed in the correct environment.
c. PyCharm indexing:
Force PyCharm to re-index your project: File > Invalidate Caches / Restart
d. NumPy installation:
Try reinstalling NumPy in your Conda environment:
conda uninstall numpy
conda install numpy
If the issue persists, you can use the help() function in Python to get documentation. For example:
import numpy as np
help(np.sin)
